# Chrome Extension inside chrome-extension:// page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have an Extension installed that is basically an HTML5 player, with an `iFrame` containing a chat; 
this extension uses a custom html page (chrome-extension://[extension-id]/**player.html**); I am trying to make an Extension that gets data from the Chat `iFrame` inside the **player.html** page.

Since i don't know almost anything about Chrome Extensions, i just started by making a simple js with a looped `console.log`:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Test Extension",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "Test",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "all_frames": true,
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "<all_urls>"
  ]
}
```

**content.js**

```
setInterval(function(){


    console.log("called");


    try {
        document.getElementsByClassName('class');
        // do something with the element
    }
    catch(error) {
        // console.error(error);

    }

},1000);
```

By looking at the Chrome Console, the `called` string is being shown in every page i visit, but **nothing is being called when i open the Extension player.html** page.

I have read somewhere that Chrome prevent Extensions to access chrome urls as a security measure; I have also other Extensions installed that access that chat `iFrame` without any problem.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: You didn't show the html structure but assuming there's one iframe that has chrome-extension:// URL of one extension, another extension can't access it by design. Well, except for chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval while your extension's own devtools panel is open.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for answering. The **player.html** is just an HTML5 player alongside the `iFrame` containing the Chat.
As i already mentioned, i have some other extensions installed that work in that `iFrame` (they change text color or replace text with images). _How are they able to do that?_ (This extensions regard Twitch.tv, just to be clear)

Comment: Without seeing the html/DOM structure I don't think we can help here. See [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: @wOxxOm Sorry for late answer. How do i post big files? Do i simply post the code in the code tag? Or use something like pastebin? (I will have to post the html with the associated js scripts).

Comment: The simplified structure shouldn't exceed a few lines of html.

Comment: @wOxxOm Nevermind. By analyzing some of the player **.js scripts**, i figured out that the Dev. added compatibility for those specific extensions that were able to work in that `iFrame`. So i cloned the extension and modified it; now it does work as intended.